# Set AlarmManager on specific date

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to set a Toast on a specific date.
I tried to use this code:

```
private void setAlertOnSpesificDate() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(info.eventYear, info.eventMonth, info.eventDayOfMonth,
                info.eventHour, info.eventMinute, 0);
        long timeToSetTheAlarm = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Receiver receiver = new Receiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("ALARM_ACTION");
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

        Intent intent = new Intent("ALARM_ACTION");
        intent.putExtra("param", "My scheduled action");
        PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent
                .getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        long t = timeToSetTheAlarm - System.currentTimeMillis();
        alarms.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, t, operation);
    }
```

and the receiver defined as following:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, intent.getStringExtra("param"),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

The problem is that the Toast in the onReceive method is fired right away, and not on the date I set.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advanced! :)

p.s. - I tried to put in the alarms.set() "timeToSetTheAlarm" insted of t, but then the toast is not fired at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting alarm with `RTC_WAKEUP`, it requires the exact time when you want to get the alarm go off, not the time from now.
So you don't have to subtract the current time:

```
alarms.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeToSetTheAlarm, operation);
```

Also note, that from target API 19, use `setExact` if you want an exact alarm time, otherwise it will optimize the alarm time to have less wakeups.

Another common mistake is that Calendar uses 0-based months (so it's recommended to use constants like Calendar.APRIL (which is 3)).